# RequiredFieldvalidator always fires for asp:FileUpload in firefox and chrome

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a asp:Fileupload and a asp:RequiredFieldValidator to force the user to choose a file. It works ok on IE but the requerired field validator allways displays an error when using Chrome or Firefox...

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="clsFileSelect" Width="255" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Display="None"
       ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ErrorMessage="É necessário seleccionar o ficheiro a anexar." ValidationGroup="AnexarDocumentos" SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

Any ideias?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ValidationGroup` property and it should work.

Good luck!

Comment: The validationgroup is needed because this code is just part of a webform with other validations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add same `ValidationGroup` as `RequiredFieldValidator` to `asp:FileUpload`

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="clsFileSelect" Width="255" ValidationGroup="AnexarDocumentos" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Display="None"
   ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ErrorMessage="É necessário seleccionar o ficheiro a anexar." ValidationGroup="AnexarDocumentos" SetFocusOnError="true" />
```